# Converting XML file into CSV with xsl

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I have a Groovy script, proceeding some querires in system and as a result I get an XML file, but for the further work I need it to be transformed into csv. Unfortunately I'm compleete nubie with the xsl, and I've tried to apply different found examples and they are all performing the result, not acceptable.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report title="Indexing Metrics">
    <header>
        <column type="text">metrics</column>
        <column type="text">value</column>
    </header>
    <rowset>
        <row>
            <cell>Start Time</cell>
            <cell />
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Sucessful Requests</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Failed Requests</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Pending Requests</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Warning Requests</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Cancelled Requests</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Added Docs</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Deleted Docs</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Updated Docs</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Indexed Content Size(byte)</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Token Size(byte)</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Average Latency(seconds)</cell>
            <cell />
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Max Latency(seconds)</cell>
            <cell />
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Documents Indexed Per Second</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
        <row>
            <cell>Bytes Indexed Per Second</cell>
            <cell>0</cell>
        </row>
    </rowset>
</report>
```

And I just need all the cells divided with comma, nothing special.
Please help!

Comment: Your XML is invalid (missing `</report>)

Comment: You are asking for a beginners tutorial for XSLT. Please use your favorite search engine for finding a few and then select the one you most easily understand. On StackOverflow this question is off-topic.

Comment: _I've tried to apply different found examples_ - Can you show us what you have tried and what is not working? There are few `<cell>` nodes that do not have any value which would not get reflected in the generated `CSV`. So when you process such `CSV`, you may be facing issues with the processed data.

Comment: Hi!I have tried such a scenario:  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
<xsl:param name="fieldNames" select="'yes'" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
 <xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>", </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position() = last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>"<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: And sorry, the file is OK, </report> just lost beacuse of copy\paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="report">
        <xsl:for-each select="header/column">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="','" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="rowset/row">
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="cell">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                    <xsl:value-of select="','" />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the following output

```
metrics,value
Start Time,
Sucessful Requests,0
Failed Requests,0
Pending Requests,0
Warning Requests,0
Cancelled Requests,0
Added Docs,0
Deleted Docs,0
Updated Docs,0
Indexed Content Size(byte),0
Token Size(byte),0
Average Latency(seconds),
Max Latency(seconds),
Documents Indexed Per Second,0
Bytes Indexed Per Second,0
```

Comment: I'm very grateful to you for your input! Yes it works!